# Using an Array in a while loop

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, switch-statement

I've been working on this for away, it's a test program for a turn based combat system. Everything is working well except the if statement. It's supposed to use the next number after you chose again, but it's always stuck on the first number. If you have a more effective method, that would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int item;
    int potion[] = { 20, 15, 10, 5 };
    int p = 0;
    int battle;
    int health = 100;
    int attack = 25;
    int ehealth;
    float eattack = 20;
    int magic = 50;
    ehealth = 100;
    cout << "1 attack, 2 attack with magic, 3 Guard attack, 4 Use items" << endl;
    while (ehealth > 0) {
        cin >> battle;
        switch (battle) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "You did " << attack << " damage!\n" << endl;
            ehealth = ehealth - attack;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "You used magic doing " << magic << " damage!\n" << endl;
            ehealth = ehealth - magic;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            cout << "You guard against the the attack!\n" << endl;
            health = health - (eattack / 10);
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            cout << "Pick an item.\n 1. potion\n" << endl;
            cin >> item;
            if (item == 1) {
                cout << "You recovered " << potion[p] << " Hp" << endl;
                health = health + potion[p];
            }
            break;
        }
        }
        cout << "The enemy attacks!\n" << endl;
        health = health - eattack;
        cout << "Enemy Health: " << ehealth << endl;
        cout << "Your Health: " << health << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider making a `struct` or `class` here to store those properties. Don't just dump them in `main`.

Comment: Also use `std::vector<int> potion = { ... }` and then you can `for (int& p : potion)`.

Comment: Re: `it's always stuck on the first number.` - you set `int p = 0;` and never change its value

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add to p after using a potion. Do this:

```
cout<<"You recovered "<< potion[p]<<" Hp"<<endl;
health = health + potion[p];
++p;
```

Comment: Probably should do `p = std::max(3, p+1);` to avoid indexing out of `potions`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to model running out of potions once you've used all the potions. I'm also going to slightly modify your potion array to make this simpler. You should use a std::array or a std::vector, depending on whether or not you expect the number of potions to get larger than your initial number of potions.

Change

```
int potion[] = { 20, 15, 10, 5 };
```

To

```
std::vector<int> potion{20, 15, 10, 5}:
```

In your use potion case, add some logic to check if you're out of potions and increment p after using a potion.

```
case 4:
  if (p >= potion.size())
  {
    std::cout << "You're out of potions!" << std::endl;
    continue;
  }
  cout << "Pick an item.\n 1. potion\n" << endl;
  cin >> item;
  if (item == 1) {
     cout << "You recovered " << potion[p] << " Hp" << endl;
     health = health + potion[p];
  }
  break;
```

There's some other things you could do to refactor this code and make it a bit cleaner as mentioned in other comments, but this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back! I'll try it out